# How can I set the console output On IntelliJ to be in the bottom when I finish running

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea, console, output

When I run Tests (from TestNG) , after the test in finished run , the console output set to the top of the text , how should I change it to be in the bottom  ?

Answer (score 0):

You may use "scroll to the end" button.
[image]

Comment: But this is the thing , I want it to be automatically without need to click on any button

Comment: "Scroll to the end" button should remember its state after test rerun, but it doesn't, it's a known bug. Please follow it at YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-199277